# Consultar páginas de terceiros

Tags: php

Problema:

Consultar uma página em outro site, passando parâmetros via `POST` e recebendo o resultado no PHP.

Eu tenho o seguinte site:

> **http://www.ciiagro.sp.gov.br/ciiagroonline/Listagens/BH/LBalancoHidricoEDR.asp**

No console quando uma pesquisa é feita aparece os seguintes parâmetros:

```
EDR
Inicio
```

Existe algum comando no PHP em que você faz o `POST` para uma página qualquer e ele faz o "download" dessa página?

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Você quer simular um POST usando PHP?

Comment: Download em que sentido?

Comment: Sim simular o post usando php. Download no sentido de salvar o código da página em uma variável por exemplo

Comment: Quer simular um POST naquela página e que retorne o código da página?

Comment: @JorgeB. Exato .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode enviar uma solicitação de `POST` usando `cURL`;

**Primeiro Passo**

Vamos verificar se ele está instalado, em seu **php.ini** verifique essa linha:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Caso esteja comentada, tire o `;`.

**Uso Básico**

```
  // Inicializamos o cURL informando um site;
  $requisicao = curl_init('www.seusite.com.br');
  // Definimos que deverá retornar o resultado;
  curl_setopt($requisicao, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  //Executa e salva o conteúdo na variável;
  $resultado = curl_exec($requisicao);
  // Encerramos a conexão;
  curl_close($requisicao);
```

**Usando POST**

```
  // 'Input' => 'Valor'
  $parametros = [
    'id' => 1,
    'relacao_id' => 234
  ];
  // Setamos POST como true
  curl_setopt($requisicao, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  // Parâmetros que serão enviados pelo POST [array]
  curl_setopt($requisicao, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros);
```

**Fonte: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/tutorial-basico-de-curl-instalacao-configuracao-e-uso/**

---

**Exemplo de cURL informando headers para recuperar o captcha do site da Receita Federal:**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/aplicacoes/atcta/cpf/captcha/gerarCaptcha.asp");
$options = [
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookiejar',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "Origin: http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br",
        "Host: www.receita.fazenda.gov.br",
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0",
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
        "Referer: http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/aplicacoes/atcta/cpf/ConsultaPublica.asp",
        "Cookie: $cookie",
        "Connection: keep-alive"
    ],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => TRUE
];

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$img = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Exemplo utilizando a API [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) para consulta de CEP:**

```
$client = new Client();
$urlCurl = 'http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/servicos/dnec/consultaEnderecoAction.do';
$request = $client->createRequest('POST', $urlCurl, [
    'body' => [
        'relaxation' => $param,
        'tipoCep' => 'ALL',
        'semelhante' => 'N',
        'cfm' => 1,
        'Metodo' => 'listaLogradouro',
        'TipoConsulta' => 'relaxation',
        'StartRow' => 1,
        'EndRow' => 100
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Host' => 'www.buscacep.correios.com.br',
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
        'Referer' => 'http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
    ],
]);
$body = $client->send($request)->getBody();
```

> **Documentação**: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php 
> **Outros Exemplos:** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/curl.examples-basic.php
>
> **[Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html)** é uma API que ajuda você nos processos de requisições, no link ao lado você pode achar a documentação, exemplos de uso e demais requerimentos para o funcionamento correto.

Comment: @JorgeB. alterei :)

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Acho que ele está falando que `curl_setopt($cURL...` deveria ser `curl_setopt($requisicao...`

Comment: André e Jorge, desculpe o erro.. já foi arrumado

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Obrigado

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft O código funcionou,mas eu não consegui acessar o resultado da página.Você tem alguma dica para eu chegar nele?

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira O resultado retornou na variável como você esperava? O que falta é conseguir capturar da variável o que você precisa, é isso?

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Retornou uma página html,ou seja,o que eu esperava,entretanto a página que retornou não é o fim da busca e sim o começo da busca.Para entender melhor entre nesse site: http://www.ciiagro.sp.gov.br/ciiagroonline/Listagens/BH/LBalancoHidricoEDR.asp e faça a consulta(são duas telas apenas).No meu post eu estou passando os parâmetros:  $dados = array(
 'EDR'=>'Araraquara',
 'Inicio'=>'16%2F2%2F2015',
 'Consultar'=>'Consultar'
  );,se não for muito em comodo analise e veja no que estou errando,pois não achei o erro

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira vou fazer alguns testes

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Obrigado Amigo,aguardo.

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21442/discussion-between-rafael-withoeft-and-rodolfo-oliveira).

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira disponibilizei aqui -> http://pastebin.com/xbZD5PsE o código funcionando, utilize Guzzle;